# NgRx Subscribe to store in Service vs in Components

Tags: ngrx-store

I'm Using ngrx/store in my app. And I ran into a question:

I need same state in several components of my module.

**What are pros and cons of using the following strategies?**
1) subscribe to the same state in every component where you need the state.

2) subscribe to the state in your module's shared service and inject service in your components.

Answer (score 1):

You should always pull the state from the store, otherwise it loses it's power as the single source of truth in your application. The selectors are memoized, so there's no performance penalty for subscribing to the store in multiple places.